# TouchPad not working on Ubuntu 20.04 and 21.04- realme i3-RMNB1001 thin and light laptop

Tags: bluetooth, mouse, touchpad, fingerprint-reader

I have a realme laptop core i3 RMNB1001 thin and light, 256 SSD, and 8GB RAM. I want to dual boot windows 10 and Ubuntu, but neither with version 20.04 and 21.04 the TouchPad is working. I also used external mouse via Bluetooth, that also not working. The TouchPad is not shown with command cat /proc/bus/input/device.

Comment: Does the laptop meet the requirements of Ubuntu 20.04 or 21.04?

Comment: @David It certainly does.

Comment: Oh you are the OP now?